# No option to delete or shrink volume in disk manager

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, disk-management

I can easily copy and delete files into my 13.72GB partition(E:) using windows explorer but I want to extent my D: by merging the space of E (13GB) onto the D: drive but there is no option to do any operations using the windows disk manager

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: We need a screenshot of disk management please

Comment: isnt the screenshot visible? @Moab

Comment: @Moab the image link was present before but I edited it to be inline.

Answer (score 1):

You can only merge unallocated space into a partition, when this space
directly follows the partition.

You need to delete the partition E: (losing all its data),
and then you will be able to extend D.

Comment: since I have formatted E:\ , it is empty and i am willing to format it or erase all data , but there is no option to delete the partition E:\, thats what i am asking

Comment: I don't see a partition E in your image. Perhaps you have formatted it and not yet assigned a drive letter. Try to assign the letter and then delete it. Device Manager should show it as Unallocated.

Comment: isnt the the drive named as `other drive` visible? thats my `E:\`

Comment: There is no E in your screenshot from the Disk Manager.